# User input validation in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, user-interface, user-input

I'm created a few forms in WinForms application and want to implement validation of user input. There are several ComboBox'es and TextBox'es. I have to check that some fields are not empty and some field require decimal number format. I know there are `Enterprise Library Validation Blocks` and integrated `ErrorProvider`. What way can you advice in terms of integration’s speed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this task without enterprise library, unless your application is really an Enterprise application.

If you are refering to System.Windows.Forms.ErrorProvider then this would be the fastest way. Is a very simple component but I does not make validation, just visual aid. So you will have to do the validation "manually".

Answer (score 0):

I have a custom class where in methods are defined. I also make use of delegates to fire a method on any event.

Edited **

This article might help: *[C# Validating TextBox Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/validatingtextbox.aspx)*

Answer (score -2):

I think the best way is to use [regular expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)

You can call the validation when each element loses focus, just like some web forms.